# Button Don't Work in PHP

Tags: php, html, button

I have created my button using a `form` whose action is *none or blank* and the method to `post`.

Then I created my code above with PHP but the code didn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Here's my code:

```
echo "<form action = '' method = 'post'>";
echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'go' value = 'Go'>";
echo "</form>";
```

And for the php above:

```
if(isset($_POST['go'])) {
header("Location:find.php");
}
```

## EDIT

For people wondering why I used PHP is this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['firstname'];
echo "<form action = '' method = 'post'>";
echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'go' value = 'Go'>";
echo "</form>";
}
```

## FULL CODE:

Sorry guys not I didn't provide much details. I'm building a friend-system and here's my code:

```
<?php session_start();
$con = mysqli_connection("localhost","root","","database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY firstname";
$join = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(isset($_POST['go'])) {
header("Location:find.php");
}

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($join)) {
echo $row['firstname'];
echo "<form action = '' method = 'post'>";
echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'go' value = 'Go'>";
echo "</form>";
} ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you just want to redirect the user, just use plain ol' javascript

Comment: if thats all the form is doing, just use plain ol' html link

Comment: @Dagon Isn't there [some way to do it with jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif)?

Comment: your code is ok. replace your header("Location: find.php");

with echo 1; if you can echo, something is conflicting with your redirect.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart i prefer mod_rewrite

Comment: @DKReigns They're not asking why you used PHP to generate the form, they're asking why you have a form with just one button, who posts to a PHP script that does nothing but redirect. Just replace the whole form with a normal `<a>` hyperlink.

Comment: full code makes less sense a button "go" next to each person taking them to the same page "find.php"

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `header('Location: http://example.com');` to redirect, you should always follow it up with a call to [`exit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php). This prevents the rest of the PHP (which you're not showing) from executing, potentially breaking the redirect.

Answer (score -1):

If you are purely talking about fixing the above redirect, you definitely need a space after the colon and I'd advise using a the qualified URL.

Comment: The space is optional

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure how to read their grammar notation in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).